# Pattern matching and compiling

Tags: python, regex, list, replace

I'm new to pattern matching and have a function as such:

```
def replaceSynonymns(title, words):
    pattern = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(words) + ')\b')
    title = re.sub(pattern, words[0], title)
    return title
```

One such example of words, is ['web', 'internet', 'online', 'digital'], hence if we put in title as 'I'm on the internet', we should get 'I'm on the web'

But unfortunately it isn't working - as I don't think the incorporation of a list into the compile pattern part is correct - any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a raw string for the last string as well:

```
>>> r'\b(' + '|'.join(words) + r')\b' 
'\\b(web|internet|online|digital)\\b'
```

Otherwise you'll end up with:

```
>>> r'\b(' + '|'.join(words) + ')\b'
'\\b(web|internet|online|digital)\x08'
                                   ^
                               not escaped
```

Or better use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
>>> r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(words))
'\\b(web|internet|online|digital)\\b'
```

As a side note you can use `.sub` on the compiled pattern itself:

```
title = pattern.sub(words[0], title)
```